# UserControl for a Row in a Grid

Tags: xaml, user-controls, grid

I have following Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- GridRow-Definition -->

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">FirstRow:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Binding_To_First_Row}" />

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">SecondRow:</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Binding_To_Second_Row}" />

    <!-- many more Label-TextBox-Rows -->
</Grid>
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to Create a UserControl which contains the Label and TextBox and properly aligns the first Column in a proper way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes, it is possible, but perhaps you should be using a DataGrid or an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate.

The simple answer to your question though is, if you need grid columns in different grids to synchronize their widths, you use the *SharedSizeGroup* attribute, e.g:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="column1" Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then in a parent element you use *Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"*

```
<StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <local:UserControl1/>
    <local:UserControl1/>
</StackPanel>
```

This synchronizes any columns (or rows) that have the same SharedSizeGroup within that scope (you can have multiple nested scopes).